# How to reset setting of multi-column footnote to its default case

Tags: footnotes, memoir

I had a page with many footnotes. Therefore to make the page in better shape, I used `\twocolumnfootnotes` command to have the footnote in two columns. But for other pages, I don't want the footnotes to be in two columns. In fact, I need a command that resets the footnote setting to its default case. How can I figure it out?

Comment: It appears \twocolumnfootnotes (which is peculiar to memoir) uses local definitions, so putting it inside a group should turn if off again when the group ends.  It also uses \footinsv@r instead of \footins, so it is conceivable that one could combine both types on the same page.  (not tested)

Comment: Dear @John Kormylo, unfortunately, your suggestion did no work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The manyfoot package supports multiple styles of footnotes at the same time, although the only standard styles are plain and para.  In this case, one would use `\footnoteS` for two column footnotes and `\footnote` for one column.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[ruled]{manyfoot}

\twocolumnfootnotes
\let\footnoteS=\footnote
\newfootnote{A}
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\footnotemark\FootnotetextA{\thefootnote}{#1}}


\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]\footnote{test \thefootnote}

  \lipsum[2]\footnote{test \thefootnote}

  \lipsum[2-7]\footnoteS{test \thefootnote}

  \lipsum[8]\footnoteS{test \thefootnote}

  \lipsum[9-16]
\end{document}
```