# Switch between 2 column and 1 column footnotes

Tags: footnotes

I sometimes want 2 column footnotes when I print many short links like this (needed to save space and make it look less awkward):

[image]

but sometimes I want in some pages just a single column, as the result can be really disturbing:

[image]

Would it be possible ? I don't mind to manually specify which page should be 2 columns and which page should be 1 column.

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{dblfnote}
\DFNalwaysdouble % for this example
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Hey, on this page\footnote{\url{https://exampleA.org}} I want footnotes\footnote{\url{https://exampleBe.org}} to be in two columns\footnote{\url{https://exampleC.org}}. This helps when footnotes\footnote{\url{https://exampleD.org}} are really small\footnote{\url{https://exampleE.org}} like here\footnote{\url{https://exampleF.org}}.

\newpage

But on this page that contains mostly long footnotes, it feels weird to cut them in two columns\footnote{See I would be better looking on a single line than here, half cut in an ugly two column layout.}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505275/how-to-reset-setting-of-multi-column-footnote-to-its-default-case